# SQL Add columns from a table as new columns to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables . They have the following structure

Table 1 (Column 1, Column 2) ;
Table 2 ( Column 3 ) ;
Table 3 (Column 4)

I want to make Table 1 display Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4

I tried :

```
Alter table table1
Add Column3 int 
Insert into table1(Column4)
Select Column3 From table2
```

I get in table1 the following:

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
VAL1        VAL1        NULL
VAL2        VAL2        NULL
NULL        NULL        VAL1
NULL        NULL        VAL2
```

but I want to get :

```
Column1     Column2    Column3
VAL1        VAL1       VAL1
VAL2        VAL2       VAL2
```

Comment: You're looking for some kind of update, if even that would work.  Please tell us what the logic is for where to place the new values.

Comment: Ordered by what? For example table 1 has values (1,2),(3,4),(5,6) and table 2 values (1)(2)(3). Should the result be (1,2,1),(3,4,2),(5,6,3) or (1,2,2),(3,4,1),(5,6,3) or yet some other?

Comment: I shouldn't have mentioned them being ordered . What I'm trying to say is that all 3 tables have the same number of rows and imagine that I would like to simply grab the Column 3 from Table2 and add it after Column 2 of Table 1 as it is .

Answer (score 0):

You should use foreign keys in such cases:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_Column1Column2 FOREIGN KEY (Column1) REFERENCES Table2(Column2)
```

[read about foreign keys here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add and update the column with existing values, use the following query

```
WITH CTE AS
   (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COL1) rnO,COL3,COL1 FROM TABLE1 UNION ALL 
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COL3) rnO2, COL3,NULL FROM TABLE2

   )
UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL3 = CTE.COL3 
FROM CTE WHERE TABLE1.COL1 =CTE.COL1 

SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT is used to add NEW rows to a table. What you want to do though is add Col3 and Col4 to table1 and then UPDATE Col3 and Col4 with the values from Table2 and Table3. As it is not mentioned in the question, I have amused that The data from Row1 in table2 and Table3 is to go to row1 of table3. This is a little more tricky as there are no matching key values in any of the tables to join the rows together.

One simple way to overcome this is to add an ID field to each table and then use that to link rows with the same value together in the UPDATE query. Another approach is to use PARTITION but as the data has no defined index the order of the rows in each table in undefined.

The third option is to use a stored procedure to create three #temp tables that contains an auto-incrementing [id] field and then append the data from each of the tables to each of the temp tables. Then the temp tables can be used to UPDATE the fields in the #temp table copy of  table1, and finally the #temp table copy of the data (now containing all fields from table1,2 and 3) can be used to update table1 joining the #temp table to table1 on column1 and column2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if order is not important

```
Alter table table1
Add Column3 int 


update table1 t1
set Column3 = (select colum3
    from table2 t2
    where t1.rownum = t2.rownum
)
```